# Confused about pulling multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: php

I am trying to create a printable attendance sheet of students that are enrolled in each class, but I am having issues since there are so many variables.

When a parent enrolls a child:
parent info is stored in table: parents2
student info is stored in table: students2
enrollment info is stored in table: enrollment2
and the class info is in table: courses2
(FYI: I had to name all the tables with the "2" on the end so I don't conflict with the current sites data. I am rewriting the site.)

Each class is available to be taken in 4 different time slots, s1_AM (session 1: AM), s1_PM, s2_AM and s2_PM

I can't post a link of the layout because the site is password protected, but basically what I want is 4 columns, with the names of the students listed below:

```
<h1>'.$title.'</h1>
<ul>
    <li class="row"><p>S1 - AM</p>'.$s1_AM.'</li>
    <li class="row"><p>S1 - PM</p>'.$s1_PM.'</li>
    <li class="row"><p>S2 - AM</p>'.$s2_AM.'</li>
    <li class="row"><p>S2 - PM</p>'.$s2_PM.'</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my idea, which is not displaying the rows of students correctly:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM enrollment2 where s1_AM = '.$id.' or s1_PM = '.$id.' or s2_AM = '.$id.' or s2_PM = '.$id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($x = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $x++) {

    $s1_AM .= $row['s1_AM'];
    $s1_PM .= $row['s1_PM'];
    $s2_AM .= $row['s2_AM'];
    $s2_PM .= $row['s2_PM'];

    $query2 = 'SELECT title FROM courses2 where id = '.$id;
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2); 
    $numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2); 
    for($x = 0; $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); $x++) {

          $title = $row2['title'];

}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm properly asking my question, I apologize!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? You're also vulnerable to `SQL injections`. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).